# Getting class method name

Tags: java, class

```
class className {
        void method1(void){
          *do something
        }
}
```

Is there any way to get the name of the class method above, and/or perhaps a pointer? I wanted to make a GUI object generated by my methodGenerator class to be displayed depending on the className and its class methods mentioned. I am learning Java at the moment.

For example, if className1 has method1, and method2; and className2 has only method1.[image]

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think only Java would do.

Comment: [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can use reflection to get method names. There are several ways of doing this, for example, if you want all the methods of the class, you can do something like this:

```
Method[] methods = ClassName.class.getMethods(); // Gives you all the methods
```

You can invoke the method by calling `invoke()` on the instance of `Method`. If the method is private, you will have to make it accessible by calling `setAccessiable(true)` on the `Method` and then calling `invoke()` on the instance of that `Method`